# Azure Data Factory copy JSON collection item "as is" into SQL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF's copy activity to copy data from a JSON source into a SQL DB.

The JSON is returned as the result of an HTTP GET operation. I have created a dataset which gets the data.

The source's structure is outlined below. The JSON object contains multiple root properties (`DataToImport`, `OtherData`). Both root properties are arrays containing a distinct collection of objects:

```json
{
  "DataToImport": [
    { name : "Item A1", id: "A1", meta: "some data 1"},
    { name : "Item A2", id: "A2", meta: "some data 2"},
    { name : "Item A3", id: "A3", meta: "some data 3"},
  ],
  "OtherData": [
    { source : "foo", value: "value 1"},
    { source : "bar", value: "value 2"},
  ]
}
```

My destination's SQL table definition looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DataToImport (
    [Id]  NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Json] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DataToImport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The goal is to copy all elements of `DataToImport` into the SQL table.

- The property `id` of each element of the JSON array `DataToImport` should be mapped to the column `Id`.
- The content of the column `Json` is supposed to be the entire item.

Expected result table:

| Id | Json |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | { name : "Item A1", id: "A1", meta: "some data 1"} |
| A2 | { name : "Item A2", id: "A2", meta: "some data 2"} |
| A3 | { name : "Item A3", id: "A3", meta: "some data 3"} |

What is the correct syntax to reference the entire item?
In the screenshot below I selected the `id` property and mapped it to 'UId'. I also took the `meta` property and mapped it to 'Json'. The result is as expected: I'm getting `A1`, `A2`, and 'A3' together with the corresponding `meta` content. But instead of `meta` I need the entire object (eg `{ name : "Item A1", id: "A1", meta: "some data 1"}`).

[image]

Alternatively, I can use the "advanced editor" which provided more flexibility but the question remains: is there a JSON path syntax that would represent the current object within the collection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are accessing the inner parts of the JSON, you have to flatten it to get the desired columns.

To flatten the JSON, use Data flows in ADF.

But Data flows did not support transforming complex JSON to SQL table.
So first transform the source JSON to another JSON with desired columns.
Then use look up and stored procedure to insert into the table.

Here I have created the JSON in Blob and same table in SQL.

**Flattening in Data flows:**


Give the source JSON to the source of the Data flow.


[image]


Flatten the JSON to get the Id column and Json Column.


[image]


Give another JSON dataset in the sink and give the single file name in sink settings.


[image]


Execute this Dataflow using pipeline. Now you will get the JSON in the blob like below.


[image]


Now, create another pipeline and use lookup to get the JSON and pass its output to a Stored procedure activity.
In look up give the above JSON dataset.


[image]


Now, go to Database and create a Stored procedure to insert the data like below.

```
create or alter procedure dbo.proc3(@myjson varchar(max))
as
begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataToImport]
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@myjson, '$')
WITH  (
        Id nvarchar(200) '$.id',
        Json nvarchar(max) '$.json' AS JSON   
    );
end
```

Go to ADF and create a Stored procedure activity and give the linked service, stored procedure and pass lookup output to parameter value like below.
myjson parameter values is

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)
```

[image]


Execute this pipeline. Now you can see the data inserted in your table.

[image]

Comment: That seems kind of overkill. I *can* get to the inner columns just fine using a copy activity. I can specify the collection from the activity's dropdown and copy over every columns I want. What I fail to get to is the complete object containing those inner properties.

Comment: @Krumelur, yeah you can get the inner columns, but copy activity asks you to map each inner column to SQL column and I think it won't give the option to copy the complete object as column. That's why I used data flows first to get the desired columns. even there copy activity won't give option for complete object. So, it is the reason for me to use look up.

Comment: If you want to skip the data flow's part, you can directly use look up and stored procedure. But you have to define the code to access inner columns in stored procedure itself. I thought it will get complex and that's why used data flows to simplify the JSON.

Comment: I gave your solution a try. Problem now is that the JSON is the result of an HTTP request. My data source is an HTTP GET. ADF is now showing me an error that HTTP datasets are not supported in data flows. :-(

Comment: One possible solution I can give is, first copy the JSON from HTTP to Blob using copy activity and then you can do this approach.